Connection between 2 MacBooks using cable instead of WiFi?
Is this possible to use a cable for connection between two MacBooks like in Sidecar for iPad?
I'm connecting to another MacBook with a smaller screen using ScreenSharing with HighPerformance profile(both laptops on Sonoma.)
I think sometimes ScreenSharing uses a Wifi Tunnel instead of direct connection.
UPD
And one sign of high performance is when I connecting to other macbook, there is no icon of vnc connection at toolbar. May be...I don't know)

You could use a LL addressing - like in this answer. Nothing required except an Ethernet cable.

To essentially network two MacBooks together with a cable, simply plug both of them into a switch and their self-discovery protocols (such as bonjour and other multicast technologies) will help them find each other. Whether screen sharing will actually pass over the cabled signal, I have no idea but its easy to test by disabling Wifi on both sides and seeing if ScreenSharing continues to function just over the cable - I don't see why not, its all just TCP/UDP over a more reliable cabled connection.

I thought about connecting without switch in the middle

Then use a crossover ethernet cable.
